# find differentially expressed genes r from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, analysis, r-package

I have dataframe that i have produce it from CEL files and normalized by RMA. now i have it in the form of dataframe that contain 16 samples divided betweem tumor and normal cells as columns and their expression levles as raws along with gene sympols as last column .

```
head(total)
       ID        N1        T1        N2        T2        N3        T3        N4        T4        N5        T5        N6        T6        N7
1 2315554  8.264940  8.267653  8.317642  8.459279  8.718600  7.921145  8.569264  8.564323  7.873743  8.073248  8.521139  8.440080  8.344196
2 2315633  8.255045  8.742490  8.157755  8.475512  8.282581  8.414478  8.532136  8.652944  8.124167  7.989419  8.241274  8.063106  8.252831
3 2315674  8.317413  8.005833  7.936746  9.151080  8.188022  7.550772  8.274640  8.516681  7.867962  7.560023  8.039914  7.972063  8.160599
4 2315739  9.635283  8.993827  9.425324  9.378666  9.855035  9.010021  9.811936  9.549161  9.378742  9.002693  9.631117  9.314967  9.949263
5 2315894 11.331040 11.082268 11.168390 11.248903 11.372028 10.651832 11.692406 11.527043 10.714782 10.848248 11.265363 11.233982 11.222504
6 2315918  6.966977  7.243905  7.941483  7.582305  7.890609  7.101653  7.499809  7.600526  6.668922  6.985750  7.807095  7.466681  6.987588
         T7        N8        T8        N9        T9       N10       T10       N11       T11       N12       T12       N14       T14
1  8.006959  8.736794  7.714123  7.890673  8.095884  8.538853  7.842322  8.542204  8.331804  8.222726  8.319711  8.546772  8.049429
2  8.514089  8.318829  8.147290  8.056879  8.096751  8.469471  8.160629  8.210366  8.353142  8.291816  8.470348  8.213987  7.935699
3  7.756448  8.417683  7.943701  7.596493  7.974143  8.189936  7.601354  8.371614  7.925672  8.316680  7.904711  8.360156  7.609378
4  9.248094  9.709039  9.294909  9.448099  9.014654  9.274544  8.559182  9.688931  9.282419  9.296614  9.298287  9.484445  8.545671
5 10.830005 11.412445 10.588834 10.590723 10.601823 11.375821 10.864110 11.523645 10.847508 11.458680 11.239654 11.208024 10.408092
6  8.191975  7.761747  7.370095  7.436801  6.852956  7.562307  6.110392  7.497195  7.780531  7.188958  7.205472  7.921733  6.469532
        N15       T15       N16       T16    Gene
1  8.039667  7.454020  8.505892  8.025953  TTLL10
2  7.999477  7.870878  8.324183  8.151734 B3GALT6
3  7.756617  7.326932  8.452201  7.979036  SCNN1D
4  9.285047  8.616807  9.375822  9.229763   PUSL1
5 11.116044 10.359807 11.625921 11.054561    VWA1
6  6.985598  6.514902  7.750057  6.927554  ATAD3C
>
```

I'm trying to find the differentially expressed genes between the normal and tumor samples but i failed to appply DESq2 to this dataframe, is there is a specific tool i could use for this dataframe to help me find the DEGs? and should i do something more to the expression values( i have alredy normalized them using RMA

Comment: You cannot apply DESeq2 to microarray data. You should try `limma`

Comment: thx!,how can i apply Limma directly on this dataframe?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials available on the Internet, this question is too general to be answered here